# How to resize a raster image (TIFF) to 800x600 using rasterio?

Tags: python, geospatial, rasterio

I want to make a subset of a raster image and put it in the dimension 800x600. I was looking through the Rasterio cookbook but it doesn't seem to allow me to input dimensions such as 800x600. Here is what I've been looking at: https://mapbox.s3.amazonaws.com/playground/perrygeo/rasterio-docs/cookbook.html

also, I saw this and thought it might work: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/windowed-rw.html

I used the Reader code snippet:

```
import rasterio
with rasterio.open('MyRasterImage.tif') as src:
    w = src.read(1, window=Window(0, 0, 800, 600))

print(w.shape)
```

However, when I go to run it it gives me the error message:

```
w = src.read(1, window = Window(0, 0, 800, 600))

NameError: name 'Window' is not defined
```

Not sure what is causing this error. I was thinking Windows was a built-in function in rasterio to where I could simply call it and resize the image to make a subset.

I'd also like to be able to display the new 800x600 image on screen  (using Spyder) not sure how this is done.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated and will upvote.

Thank you

Comment: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.windows.html#rasterio.windows.Window

Comment: @Rishav Thanks, I'm not seeing the anything standing out as far as the error goes. What could be going wrong here?

Comment: @Rishav in my Spyder IDE it tells me that 'Window' is an undefined name.

Comment: what I mean is that, first do `from rasterio.windows import Window`.

Comment: @Rishav Thank you. I put from rasterio.windows import Window and then import rasterio after that. It gives me the error message:   ImportError: cannot import name 'Window'

Comment: That’s not... possible. `from rasterio.windows import Window` works on my machine. Python 3.6.6 and rasterio (1.0.9)

Comment: I reinstalled everything. Then I changed that line in my code to:    w = src.read(1, window = rasterio.windows.Window(0, 0, 800, 600))…. now I have the error: ValueError: invalid window structure; expecting ((row_start, row_stop), (col_start, col_stop))

Comment: Try passing in (0,0) and (800,600)

Comment: As tuples? I did it like:     w = src.read(1, window = rasterio.windows.Window((0, 0),(800, 600)) and now I get the error for the print(w.shape) saying its SyntaxError: invalid syntax. When I remove the print statement then it gives the error: File "C:/Users/new/Desktop/Raster.py", line 7...…..^ SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: Nevermind, that was just a missing parentheses. The real error is: TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'width' and 'height'

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy
import rasterio
from matplotlib import pyplot
from rasterio.windows import Window

width = 800
height = 600

with rasterio.open('MyRasterImage.tif') as src:
    w = src.read(1, window=Window(0, 0, width, height))
    profile = src.profile
    profile['width'] = width
    profile['height'] = height
    # Create output
    result = numpy.full((width, height), dtype=profile['dtype'], fill_value=profile['nodata'])

#writting
with rasterio.open('/tmp/sampled_image.tif', 'w', **profile) as dataset:
    dataset.write_band(1, result)

#plotting
with rasterio.open('/tmp/sampled_image.tif') as src:
    pyplot.imshow(src.read(1), cmap='pink')
    pyplot.show()
```